# Javascript GetElementById from a different file

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage with a `href` linking to a second page. The second page has an SWF. I want the `a` tag in the first webpage to be able to `GetElementById`, the SWF object. Is this possible?

Edit: What I need to do: I have a main page with 2 frames aligned vertically. The second frame loads different pages based on some button clicks. One such page is an swf. When one button is clicked I want the page to redirect to the swf page and also send parameters to the swf which is why I need the GetElementById

Comment: Why dont you describe *what* you're trying to achieve, rather than *how* you're trying to achieve it. We might have more luck answering your question!

Comment: Are all pages from the same domain? You can access objects loaded into frames, but only if they're from the same origin.

Answer (score 0):

You like to pass parameters to another  HTML documents.  Your choices are:

- add request parameter and evaluate it in another page (javascript has access to URL and can parse it. Drawback (possible)  - server side sees this parameter )
- add some information as anchor - javascript on the target page can evaluate this and do whatever necessary. Server does not see this, and search engines do not evaluate this ( usually )